# Anchor and Dock property missing Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, properties, mdi

I am trying to make resizing adjustments to my MDI application in visual studio 2010 and i cannot see the anchor and dock properties  in the properties tab when i click on my form. Is there a setting i need to turn on? Does anyone know the change i need to make?

Comment: What is an "MDF application"?

Comment: There are no anchors or docking for an MDI child form, because MDI itself positions them within the MDI parent. You can dock controls that are placed within the MDI child, but not the form itself. If you need to be able to position the form at a specific location inside the parent, you shouldn't be using MDI.